I’m trying to find all of the cycles of a directed graph. Is there a more efficient way to do this?
Here’s the graph:



My current strategy is to make an adjacency matrix, then follow it, like if A can go to B, then I go to B’s row and see which points B can go to, all the way until I reach the starting point again.
However, this was really time-consuming, and I was wondering if there was any more efficient way to do this.
Here’s all the cycles I found if it helps:
ABA ABDA ABEA ABEDA ADA ADCBA ADCBEA BAB BADCB BDAB BDCB BEAB BEADB
BEADCB BEDAB BEDCB CBADC CBDC CBEADC CBEDC DABD DABED DAD DAED DCBAD
DCBD DCBED EABE EADCBE EDABE EDCBE

If there isn't some kind of systematic structure to the graph, odds are there isn't a shortcut to finding all the cycles. Not saying there isn't a better way, but to my untrained eye it looks too chaotic for any "clever" solution.

Since detecting a Hamiltonian cycle is an NP-complete problem, enumerating all cycles is NP-hard. Now, that certainly doesn't prove that brute force is the best you can do. There are better algorithms, as mentioned here. But it does suggest that you shouldn't expect a really easy answer.

Not sure if this is what you’re looking for, but you can input the directed graph into Sage using the adjacency matrix, and then ask Sage for directed cycles.

If you are allowed to solve this programmatically, I would suggest doing a BFS/DFS while keeping track of the path traversed, starting from every node in the graph. If you encounter a visited node, then add the path to the list of cycles. I add a very crude pseudocode below for a reference to implement in your choice of programming languages. You can try to optimize it further with memoization and such, but for a small graph this will do:
result = array()
for node in graph:
  toCheck = array(node)
  while toCheck is not empty:
    currentPath = pop first (BFS)/ last (DFS) element of toCheck
    lastNode = last char of currentPath
    get all adjacent node from lastNode
    for each adjacent node:
      if adjacent node is in currentPath:
        add currentPath + adjacent node to result
      else:
        newPath = add adjacentNode to currentPath
        push newPath to toCheck
return result


We can be a little bit systematic about this. For instance, we can do it by cycle size.

The double arrows are ABA and ADA
We can easily see there is exactly one 3-cycle that contains E, and exactly one that contains C. And there is exactly one that contains neither.
We split into cases depending on which vertex is not included:

A: Since we must include C, we must have the sequence DCB in our cycle, and DCBED is indeed a cycle
B: C can't be in a cycle without B, so none
C: Since we must include E, we must have the BE edge. BEDAB is a cycle, but BEADB is not
D: C can't be in a cycle without D, so none
E: Since we must include C, we must have the sequence DCB in our cycle, and DCBAD is indeed a cycle


All five. Since we must include C, we must have the sequence DCB in our cycle. And since we must include E, we must have BE. Which means we must have DCBE in our cycle. And DBCEAD is indeed a cycle.

So those are all the 9 cycles.
Note that your list contains a lot of duplicates. For instance, your ABDA is the same as your BDAB is the same as your DABD.

It is a planar graph - You can move vertex E inside the triangle ABD. This gives you a planar embedding with the four triangular faces ABE, ADE, BED, BCD (plus the outside area, which we can ignore).
There are the 2-cycles ABA and ADA, but any other cycle in the planar graph is a loop around a region consisting of one or more adjacent faces. So now you merely have to emumerate these regions, and check if the arrow directions allow for a cycle. If there is a cycle around a region, then you can choose any of its vertices as the start/end vertex, so in the list below I only show one cycle in each case.
0 faces: ABA, ADA
1 face: ABEA, BDCB (ADE not possible at E, BDE not possible at B)
2 faces: ABEDA, BEDCB (ADE+BDE not possible at B, and ABE+BDE not possible at E)
3 faces: ABDA, ADCBEA (ABE+BDE+BCD not possible at E, and ABE+ADE+BCD not adjacent)
4 faces: ADCBA
